# Rewriting links with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

HeIIo, I need to implement the following rules:

```
1) to understand root/<something> as root/index.php?p=<something>
```

and

```
2) to understand root/<something>:specific as root/specific.php?p=<something>
```

I use the following rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^root/([^/\.]+)/?$ root/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^root/([^/\.]+)/?$:specific root/specific.php?p=$1 [L]
```

My problem is that it treats root/something and root/something:specific as the same url and understands both as root/index.php?p=something

Can someone help me to come up with a correct rewriting.
Thank you.

Comment: Not 100% sure, since I have limited experience with .htaccess rewriting, but I believe the order of your rules is important. Most specific first, and the most general last.

Comment: [and the moment you set `$` nothing after it will be evaluated. See this link for a basic walk-through on rewriting URL.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your regex and reverse order of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^root/([^:]+):(.+)$ root/specific.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^root/([^/.]+)/?$ root/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```